# Vectors belonging to each component of decomposition of semi-simple Lie group representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Say that $W$ is a $SL_4(\mathbb{Q})$ representation that decomposes into irreducibles (using the notation of Fulton-Harris) $$W = \Gamma_{a,b,c} \oplus \Gamma_{d,e,f}$$

Now say that I have a vector $v \in W$, and I know something about it (maybe I can write it as a wedge product or tensor product of the basis vectors for the standard representation). How can I know if $v$ belongs to $\Gamma_{a,b,c}$ or $\Gamma_{d,e,f}$ or if it is a sum of elements that belong to both irreducible subrepresentations?

I've tried to pin down some very easy (but nontrivial - so $W$ itself is not irreducible) cases. For example, if
$$W = V \otimes V^* = \Gamma_{1,0,1} \otimes \Gamma_{0,0,0}$$
what would vectors belonging to $\Gamma_{1,0,1}$ or $\Gamma_{0,0,0}$ or neither look like? What do the highest weight vectors look like in the form $\Sigma w_i \otimes w_j^*$?

(I also don't mean for my question to be specific to $SL_4(\mathbb{Q})$...it would be great to eventually do this for any semisimple Lie group! At the very least for $SL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ for any $n$.)

Comment: Yes @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm ultimately trying to understand a specific $SL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ representation, but first am getting comfortable with the background (hence this question)

Comment: Note Fulton and Harris is about representations of **complex** Lie algebras/groups so be careful trying to apply its results to ones over $\mathbb{Q}$. In the complex setting anyway, the splitting of $V\otimes V^*$ is precisely that into tracefree part and the 1-dimensional span of the identity. More generally this is unclear unless your $W$ is exactly a tensor product as, while $\Gamma_{a,b,c}$ can always be found in $V^{\otimes a} \otimes (\bigwedge^2V)^{\otimes b} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes c}$, it will also occur in other tensor products.